# how to fetch 1 by 1

Tags: sql, database

```
sno acco_no amount

1    50001     5000
2    50002     4000
3    50001     2500
4    50002     3100
5    50002     3400
6    50001     1500
```

I want to take 50001's last 2 records one by one.

```
 select sno, acco_no, amount 
 from table 
 where acco_no = 50001 
 order by tno desc fetch first 2 rows only

sno acco_no amount
  6     50001     1500
  3    50001      2500
```

but I want to fetch 1 by 1 record like following

1) first step

```
select sno, acco_no, amount 
from table 
where acco_no = 50001 

sno acco_no amount
  6     50001     1500
```

2) second step

```
select sno, acco_no, amount 
from table 
where acco_no = 50001

sno acco_no amount
  3     50001     2500
```

Note : should not delete any records

Comment: First of all: **WHY!?!?!** and secondly: for **what database** ??

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to put business logic/workflow in the data layer, which isn't necessarily bad, but in this case I think you'd have it easier if you could step through the recordset at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use LIMIT / OFFSET for that stuff, depends on the database you use...
for Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html

for MySQL the Limit-Keyword have 2 parameters for limit and offset-definition

1st

```
select sno, acco_no, amount 
from table 
where acco_no = 50001 LIMIT 0,1

sno acco_no amount
  3     50001     2500
```

2nd

```
select sno, acco_no, amount 
from table 
where acco_no = 50001 LIMIT 1,1

sno acco_no amount
  3     50001     2500
```